# Extra fire simulation on iPad device

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, ipad

I have with me an iOS app for iPad which creates a few fire simulations over a png.Well,its working well exactly how we wanted it but when we are testing it on a device,we get an extra fire simulation.Heres the screen:

**iPad Simulator:**

[image: This is how it should display (iPad simulator)]

**iPad Device:**

[image: This is how it's displaying (iPad device)]

*EDIT:*

Thanks for your responses.I hoped that the response here wouldn't be strong enough so i didn't place the code previously.Apologies.

This is a snippet from my FireplacesAnimation.m which is responsible for generating the emitter

```
-(ParticleEmitter *)generateParticle
{
Texture *particleTexture = [[Texture alloc] initWithName:@"particle.png"]; 
return [[ParticleEmitter alloc] initParticleEmitterWithTexture:particleTexture
                                                      position:Vector2fMake(0, 0)
                                        sourcePositionVariance:Vector2fMake(100, 10)
                                                         speed:5.25f
                                                 speedVariance:0.2f
                                              particleLifeSpan:0.75f    
                                      particleLifespanVariance:0.25f
                                                         angle:90.0f
                                                 angleVariance:0
                                                       gravity:Vector2fMake(0.0f, 0.5f)
                                                    startColor:Color4fMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
                                            startColorVariance:Color4fMake(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f)
                                                   finishColor:Color4fMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f)  
                                           finishColorVariance:Color4fMake(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f)
                                                  maxParticles:500
                                                  particleSize:20
                                          particleSizeVariance:50
                                                      duration:500.0f
                                                 blendAdditive:YES];}
```

and i am using the following code to create the frame buffer:

```
(BOOL)createFramebuffer {

glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
}

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

aand.. drawview:

```
(void)drawView {
if(fireStopcount > 75){    
self.alpha = 1.0;
static BOOL viewInitialized = NO;
static CFTimeInterval lastTime;

CFTimeInterval time;
time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

float delta = (time - lastTime);
lastTime = time;    
// Replace the implementation of this method to do your own custom drawing

[explosion1 update:delta];
[explosion2 update:delta];
[explosion3 update:delta];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
//NSLog(@"Draw Animation Fire Places View");
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

if(!viewInitialized)
{
    //viewInitialized = YES;
    glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrthof(0.0f, 320.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

}

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

if(explosion1.active != YES)
{
    explosion1.angle = 90.0f;
    explosion1.particleSize = 20.0f;
    explosion1.sourcePosition = [self firstFirePlacePoint];
    explosion1.active = YES;
    explosion1.duration = rand() % 2 + 1;
    explosion1.sourcePositionVariance = Vector2fMake(20,20);
}    

if(explosion2.active != YES)
{
    explosion2.angle = 90.0f;
    explosion2.sourcePosition = [self secondFirePlacePoint];
    explosion2.active = YES;
    explosion2.duration = rand() % 2 + 1;
    explosion2.sourcePositionVariance = Vector2fMake(20,20);
}

if(explosion3.active != YES)
{
    explosion3.angle = 90.0f;
    explosion3.sourcePosition = [self thirdFirePlacePoint];
    explosion3.active = YES;
    explosion3.duration = rand() % 2 + 1;
    explosion3.sourcePositionVariance = Vector2fMake(20,20);
}

[explosion1 renderParticles];
[explosion2 renderParticles];
[explosion3 renderParticles];

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
} 
else
{
fireStopcount++;
}}
```

**Thanks for your time guys.**

Comment: Your image links seem broken. Without code, how are we supposed to be able to help you?

Comment: supplied the code.I was not allowed to place images.So i linked them instead.Awaiting response..

Comment: Oh, didn't realize you  need permissions for images. I have updated your post to include the images instead of links.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on your method of producing fire as you haven't shared any code, so I'm going to suggest a new one for creating fire.

http://particledesigner.71squared.com/

Download that and take a look at the fire animations on there. In the meantime edit your answer with some code and a little bit more about the framework you're using (if you're using one), for example cocos2d.

Comment: edited with code.While you look at it,i shall look at your link inshallah.Using opengl with quartz framework.